# Trying to format SQL data into my html page

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm just learning SQL, and I was wondering if it's even possible to do this. The data output I have looks like this:

[image]

in the DB it **doesn't have** a col named ZUM Tool Groups, and I was wondering if it's possible to assign the SQL output to include the first column.

Example: when the query outputs **CV403 PROD 88** to include ARC_SOUTH  on the Left hand side (note picture below).

[image]

is this possible? **Note:** I can't edit this table in the DB to include the first column so I am looking for a second solution. Thank you in advance!

Here is the SQL query I have.

```
Select 
       g.entity as MISTI,
       t.cur_state      as STATE,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) AS HRS

From Entity_Grp_Lst g
left outer join trk_id_def t
on g.facility = t.facility
and g.grp_type = t.grp_type
and g.entity=t.entity
and g.grp_type = '720'
WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD','NM','TERM','NULL','IDLE', 'YER', 'I05', 'I07')
and Entity_Grp_type = '041'
and g.ENTITY_GRP in ('THINFILM')
and (g.entity like 'CV403%' or
g.entity like 'CV406%' or
g.entity like 'CV405%' or
g.entity like 'CV132%' or
g.entity like 'MT105%' or
g.entity like 'MT106%' or
g.entity like 'MT117%' or
g.entity like 'MT118%' or
g.entity like 'MTA08%' or
g.entity like 'MTA13%' or
g.entity like 'MTA09%' or
g.entity like 'MTA30%' or
g.entity like 'MTA31%' or
g.entity like 'MTA32%' or
g.entity like 'MTA33%' or
g.entity like 'MTA34%' or
g.entity like 'CEN01%' or
g.entity like 'CEN02%' or
g.entity like 'CEN03%' or
g.entity like 'CVN31%' or
g.entity like 'MTA12%' or
g.entity like 'MTA14%' or
g.entity like 'MTA21%' or
g.entity like 'MTA22%' or
g.entity like 'CVN13%' or
g.entity like 'CVN14%' or
g.entity like 'CVN32%' or
g.entity like 'CVA40%' or
g.entity like 'CVA41%' or
g.entity like 'MTA40%' or
g.entity like 'MTA43%' or
g.entity like 'MTT01%' or
g.entity like 'CVN02%' or
g.entity like 'CVN03%' or
g.entity like 'VN05%' or
g.entity like 'CV170%' or
g.entity like 'CV172%' or
g.entity like 'CV173%' or
g.entity like 'CV174%' or
g.entity like 'CV175%' or
g.entity like 'CV176%' or
g.entity like 'CV177%' or
g.entity like 'CV178%' or
g.entity like 'CV179%' or
g.entity like 'MT130%' or
g.entity like 'MT131%' or
g.entity like 'MT132%' or
g.entity like 'MT133%' or
g.entity like 'MT134%' or
g.entity like 'MT135%' or
g.entity like 'MT136%' or
g.entity like 'MT137%' or
g.entity like 'MT138%' or
g.entity like 'MT139%' or
g.entity like 'MT140%' or
g.entity like 'MT141%' or
g.entity like 'MT142%' or
g.entity like 'MT143%' or
g.entity like 'MTA04%' or
g.entity like 'MTA05%' or
g.entity like 'MTA10%' or
g.entity like 'MT102%' or
g.entity like 'MT119%' or
g.entity like 'MT120%' or
g.entity like 'MT121%' or
g.entity like 'MT122%' or
g.entity like 'MT123%' or
g.entity like 'MT103%' or
g.entity like 'MT104%' or
g.entity like 'MT107%' or
g.entity like 'MT108%' or
g.entity like 'MT109%' or
g.entity like 'MT110%' or
g.entity like 'MT111%' or
g.entity like 'MT112%' or
g.entity like 'MT113%' or
g.entity like 'MT114%' or
g.entity like 'MT115%' or
g.entity like 'MT116%' or
g.entity like 'MTA07%' or
g.entity like 'MTV01%' or
g.entity like 'TA41%' or
g.entity like 'MTA42%' or
g.entity like 'CV420%' or
g.entity like 'CV208%' or
g.entity like 'CV404%' or
g.entity like 'CV421%' or
g.entity like 'CVN12%' or
g.entity like 'CVN16%' or
g.entity like 'CVN18%' or
g.entity like 'CVN15%' or
g.entity like 'CVN17%' or
g.entity like 'CVN01%' or
g.entity like 'CVA81%' or
g.entity like 'CVA82%' or
g.entity like 'CV131%' or
g.entity like 'CV133%' or
g.entity like 'CV134%' or
g.entity like 'CV135%' or
g.entity like 'CV136%' or
g.entity like 'CVA04%' or
g.entity like 'CVN04%' or
g.entity like 'CVN06%' or
g.entity like 'CV203%' or
g.entity like 'CV204%' or
g.entity like 'CV205%' or
g.entity like 'CV206%' or
g.entity like 'CV207%' or
g.entity like 'CV209%' or
g.entity like 'CV210%' or
g.entity like 'CV211%' or
g.entity like 'CV213%' or
g.entity like 'CV214%' or
g.entity like 'CV317%' or
g.entity like 'CVN10%' or
g.entity like 'CVN11%' or
g.entity like 'CVN19%' or
g.entity like 'CV310%' or
g.entity like 'CV310%' or
g.entity like 'CV312%' or
g.entity like 'CV313%' or
g.entity like 'CV314%' or
g.entity like 'CV315%' or
g.entity like 'CV311%' or
g.entity like 'CV316%' or
g.entity like 'CV318%' or
g.entity like 'CVA50%' or
g.entity like 'CVN21%' or
g.entity like 'CVN22%' or
g.entity like 'CV505%' or
g.entity like 'CV508%' or
g.entity like 'CV509%' or
g.entity like 'CV510%' or
g.entity like 'CV512%' or
g.entity like 'CV520%' or
g.entity like 'CV521%' or
g.entity like 'CV522%' or
g.entity like 'CV104%' or
g.entity like 'CV105%' )

AND ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) > 48  
order by t.cur_state_DTTM desc


";
```

Comment: How ARC_SOUTH is derived from  CV403 PROD 88 ?

Comment: it's not I was wondering if it's possible to somewhat hard code it in?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the first columns in the DB, but know how you want MIST values mapped, then you can do that in your query. But ideally you find a way to hold these relationships in your DB instead of keeping a manual mapping in a query:

```
Select 
      CASE WHEN g.entity like 'CV4%' then 'ARC_SOUTH'
         WHEN g.entity = 'CV132' then 'BPSG'
         ELSE 'COBALT'
       end as ZUM_TOOL_GROUP,
       g.entity as MISTI,
       t.cur_state      as STATE,
       ROUND(((SYSDATE-t.cur_state_dttm)*24),2) AS HRS
From Entity_Grp_Lst g
left outer join trk_id_def t
on g.facility = t.facility
and g.grp_type = t.grp_type
and g.entity=t.entity
and g.grp_type = '720'
WHERE t.cur_state NOT IN ('PROD','NM','TERM','NULL','IDLE', 'YER', 'I05', 'I07')
and Entity_Grp_type = '041'
and g.ENTITY_GRP in ('THINFILM')
and (g.entity like 'CV403%' or
 ...
```